# How can I compare the number of transactions in the first weeks or months of different stores

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I need to make a comparison of the number of transactions per week and month of different stores since its opening date. The problem is that the stores has a different opening date.

So, The idea is to compare the number of transactions in the first weeks or months

**That's what I have:**

```
 Canal Key 1

   Recount FactTransactions

                              Month1-2015 Month2-2015 Month3-2015 Month4-2015 Month5-2015 Month6-2015

 Type of store     Cod Store 

Spain     
         2          Store 1                                              5         6        10
                    Store 2      10          20            40            50        60       85        
         4          
                    Store 3      31          45            100           315       441      625              
                    Store 4                                10            20        32       45
Portugal
        1       
                    Store 5                                                                 12
```

**That's what I want to obtain (comparing different stores since its opening date):**

```
    Canal Key 1

   Recount FactTransactions

                              Month1 (or Week) Month2 Month3 Month4 Month5 Month6

 Type of store     Cod Store 

Spain     
         2          Store 1       5              6      10
                    Store 2       10             20     40     50     60       85        
         4          
                    Store 3       31             45     100    315    441      625              
                    Store 4       10             20      32    45
Portugal
        1       
                    Store 5                                                                 12
```

**That's my data model:**

```
 FacTransaccion: *Measures* Recount FactTransaction / Amount / Amount discount / Unit Price

 DimDate: *Hierachy* Date (YYYYMMDD) / Month / Month Name / Week of Month / Week of year / Year (It's the same Dimdate than AdventureWorksDW2008 with its member calculation and relationship)

 DimProduct: *Hierachy* Product Key

 DimStore: *Hierachy* Type of store / Store key / Opening date / Country 

 DimType: *Hierachy* Type of transaction

 DimCanal: *Hierachy* Canal  (there are two channel where people can buy)
```

Reading a lot about MDX, after a thousand times of MDX. I don't have anything.

Several attemps:

**Attempt #1:**

```
SELECT CROSSJOIN({TAIL([Dim Store].[Opening date].Children, 30) }, { [Measures].[Transactiones] }) ON COLUMNS
    ,{ [Dim Store].[Store names].Children} ON ROWS FROM [CUBE]
```

**Attempt #2:**  (It does not work) It seems to me better than first attempt.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Count] AS
SUM([Dim Store].[Name Store].currentmember*Tail([Dim Store].[Opening Date].children,1),
[Measures].[Count Fact Transacciones])
SELECT {[Measures].[Count]} ON COLUMNS,
{[Dim Store].[Name Store].[All]} ON ROWS
from [CUBE]
```

Comment: So store one opened in month 4, store 2 in month 1 and so on?

Comment: Yes. There are like 40 stores, each one of them has a different opening date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally did it! Without a complicated set, just creating a new dimension "DimOrdinal" with values 1-9999, It's connected to the Fact table with a new Ordinal column which contents a numerical value. That new column contents the datediff in days to the openingdate :D

Answer (score 5):

We really need more detail on your measures and dimensions to give you an exact answer on this, but since you are using SSAS a few general rules apply.

If you add more detail I can expand my answer to be in line with your data model.

Since you want to compare the number of transactions you should have a `measure` showing the number of transactions.

As you want to compare them over time you would also need a `Time Dimension` with a `hierarchy`.

If you have both those prerequisites you can resort to `MDX` to calculate sums and differences of your measure over your dimension hierarchies and members.

In essence what you need to try is to construct a [set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146040.aspx) and [sum your measure over that set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145484.aspx).

```
Sum({[opening date]:[opening date+2weeks]},[Measures].[Number of transactions])
```

The hard part in your problem will be constructing the `set` however. **And that's the part we can't answer without your data model and some sample data.**

As you say you have different start dates for different stores you could use a property on the store dimension indicating it's start date and use that to construct a set to sum over.

A great resource to get started with MDX is the [Stairway to MDX series on SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72404/).

You should look at functions like [PeriodsToDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144925.aspx).

You also have the option of resorting to [VBA functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510163.aspx) and could use that to use [DateDiff and DateAdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588000/using-datediff-in-ssas-mdx) if you can't get there with pure MDX.

You can even write your own [SSAS Stored procedure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175340%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) if all else fails.

Comment: Thank you. It's a great resource to start with MDX. But I also need help to construct the set. Meanwhile I'll try to practice with AdventureWorks. Let me know if you need more information about my data model

Comment: @Miguel didn't have time yet, I'll look into an example when I find some spare time but I'm a bit overloaded at the moment

Comment: Hello @Tom V, as I told you I'm still working on it. I think I have advanced a lot, I have a question; How can I integrate the MDX in Analysis Services? I mean, I'm doing the query in SQL Server Management Studio, but I don't know How can I integrate it in SQL Data Tools (BI SSAS)

Comment: I'm not able to do it. I have tried a lot of querys, but it's impossible for me